# Why can't I print out an image on flutter?

Tags: error-handling, syntax, syntax-error, flutter, flutter-layout

By using the following code, I'm unable to print out the same results as the example I've listed. Does anyone know why? 
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCHbm.png) [What I'm actually getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b5h5.png)[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gxEM.png)

Comment: put your code in your question, not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure that you added the reference of your image inside the file `pubspec.yaml` (I guess you have a typo btw -> `assets` instead of `assests`

```
    flutter:
       assets:
       - assets/vegetables.jpg
```

After that I added some properties to your `Column` widget

> mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

To avoid your Column fill all the space in vertical, it's like `wrap_content` in Android

> crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

To expand the child full width.

> textAlign: TextAlign.center

To align the text to the center

```
        @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("FBLA Quizz!!"),
              ),
              body: Card(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset("assets/vegetables.jpg"),
                    Text(
                      "Food Paradise",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

Comment: Extension are different. JPEG and jpg check it